# iPhone + resize UITableView

Tags: uitableview

I have a view in which I have UITableView (grouped style). In the Interface builder, I am resizing the UITableView so that it looks like a small portion in center of the screen.

But when I run the application, UITableView takes up the whole area of screen and does not look like the small portion in center of screen (which I had set in Interface builder).

I tried to resize the tableView programmatically in the viewDidLoad method as tableView.frame = CGRectMake (0.0,0.0,100.0,100.0), but still the tableView occupies the whole area of screen.

Please help.

Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your table view's got autoresized. Try to fiddle with the autoresizing settings.

If your table view is the main view then it will automatically fill the whole view controller's space regardless of the autoresizing settings. In that case, make an empty `UIView` as the root view and put the `UITableView` as a subview of it.

Comment: If you downvote it, please "insert comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong", or add another answer.

Comment: Thank you. After an hour of searching, I finally found autoresizing as being the culprit.